# SharePoint 2013 Search: Get alternate access mappings in crawled property

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, alternate-access-mapping

When the content is crawled, the crawled properties are getting the original URL's in it rather than the alternate access mappings.

Is there a way to get AAM?

Answer (score 2):

Search will use the default zone and return results from the query request zone unless you don't have a matching AAM entry, in which case it will return the default. If you want results from the AAM zone, make your query from that zone.

Answer (score 1):

Try change Start Addresses in Content Source to AAM instead internal URL

Example:

from this `http://sp13`

to this    `http://sp13.alternate.access.mapping`

Crawl and see if that work ;)